# Prevent a boolean variable returning to false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, boolean, boolean-logic

I just want to check I'm doing this right. I have a variable `bar` that starts **false** and is set **true** if a function `foo()` returns **false**, however I check `foo()` against several arguments and don't want `bar` returning to **false** if it is ever set **true**. This is what I've written:

```
var bar = false;
var collection = []; // this is filled with arguments for foo
for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    bar = !foo(collection[i]) || bar;
}
```

Should that do the trick? Or is there maybe a simpler way?

Comment: Does "foo()" have side-effects that you want to happen for each member of the collection?  Also, **don't forget `var` for the variable "i" in the loop!**

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, but by having bar in an OR like that you do guarantee that once true it will stay true.  Both of pointy's points are good ones - mind, bar will most likely be out of foo's scope.

Comment: When you say "returning to `false`," do you mean "being set to `false`"? Variables do not return, only functions do.

Comment: Yes, I want foo() to execute for each array element. Have added var i! Also, yes I meant not be set to false after being set to true.

Answer (score 3):

Change your for loop to do this and it should jump out as soon as it is set to true:

```
var bar = false;
var collection = []; // this is filled with arguments for foo
for(i = 0; i < collection.length && !bar; i++) {
    bar = !foo(collection[i]) || bar;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `var` declaration for "i"!

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. Unfortunately in this case I need foo() to execute for every array element regardless.

Comment: @tamewhale In that case your code works fine. You can test things like this easily on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/s6qN3/

Comment: I would swap the `||` part - the function is always executed. Unless you find this necessaty, `bar || !foo...` can be faster, depending on what kind of expensive things `foo` does.

Answer (score 0):

I often use `Array.maps()` and `Array.includes()` for such things.

Array.map() runs a function on each item in the array and returns the value into a new array.

Array.includes() tests an array to see if it contains a value.

```
let collection = []; // this is filled with arguments for foo
let test = collection.map((currentItem) => {
  return foo(currentItem);
});
return test.includes(true);
```